# Mongo index doesn't make query faster

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design, database

Solved. Just change db.test.ensureIndex(['name']) => to db.test.ensureIndex({'name':1});

---

I was testing MongoDB today. I have test collection with 100 000 documents. Each document has such structure {_id:123123, name: 'foo123123'}

Test code written in PHP

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$db = $mongo->test;
$collection = $db->test;

$start = microtime(true);

for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++){
    $obj = $collection->findOne(array('name'=>'foo'.$i));
}

$end = microtime(true);
var_dump($end-$start);
```

First test without index on name field is 21 seconds
Than I add index

> db.test.ensureIndex(['name']);
>
> db.test.getIndexes();
>   [
>           {
>                   "v" : 1,
>                   "key" : {
>                           "_id" : 1
>                   },
>                   "ns" : "test.test",
>                   "name" : "*id*"
>           },
>           {
>                   "v" : 1,
>                   "key" : [
>                           "name"
>                   ],
>                   "ns" : "test.test",
>                   "name" : "0_"
>           }
>   ]

And repeat test. And got 21 seonds again. Why mongo doesn't use index in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `explain` method to view the execution plan and find out whether or not it is using the index correctly.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

I also think that you want to update your index creation command to this:

db.things.ensureIndex({"name": 1})

It isn't an array, but rather a key-value pair where the key is the property you want to index and the value is 1 or -1 depending on whether you want it to be indexed ascending or descending.

Check the docs for indexes:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CreationOptions

Comment: For my query it is

{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 100000,
        "nscannedObjects" : 100000,
        "n" : 1,
        "millis" : 68,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}

Comment: So then youre correct that it is not using an index - if it were, it would say that the cursor were a B-Tree Index rather than a basic cursor.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information about indexes - please have a look

Comment: Don't you know why it happens?

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I change my command to db.things.ensureIndex({"name": 1}) and now it is using index

Comment: Excellent - are your queries faster now?

Comment: Yes. Was 21 sec. Now it is 1.15 sec ))